# Sandcastle Topic Grouping

Tags: .net, sandcastle

We're using Sandcastle to generate our source code documentation with our build process.  This is working great for creating API level doc for classes, methods, properties, etc.  Additionally, Sandcastle allows you to add summaries to your namespaces as well as "Conceptual Content".  We're creating Conceptual Content files for various "How To" topics like as well as architecture diagrams, etc.  All this is working great.

Does anyone know if there's a way in Sandcastle to group this content?  By default, Sandcastle seems to create all of this API documentation at the root of the help tree as well as any Conceptual Content.  I would like to have a node in the tree like "API Documentation" and have all of the source code doc under that node, and then have other groupings of the other doc topics we have.  I'm struggling to find a way to do this in Sandcastle.  I've seen other commercial products have this type of grouping in their chm files, but I suspect they're using something like RoboHelp.

Is there a way to achieve this with Sandcastle?

Answer (score 1):

Eric Wodruff answered my question [over on the CodePlex discussion boards](http://shfb.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=63688&ANCHOR#Post216610).  The short answer is use RootNamespaceContainer and RootNamespaceTitle to do basic grouping.  Beyond that, content plugins are the way to go.  Hope this helps someone else